# Bootstrap margin - Broken rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm at the beginning in Bootstrap framework.

I have this Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
           <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
          <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>

          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x350"  class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Featured Work</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300"class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p>
            <a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300"class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p>
            <a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300"class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p>
            <a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300"class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p>
            <a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to add some margin on the right in the title,

```
---------------------------
| Image         Title ++ Margin
|                          | 
|                          |
|                          |
----------------------------
```

If i try to add some class in another css class like

```
.testclass{
margin-right:xxpx/zz%;
}
```

And i create a div in which i put the 
I set the div's class to tesclass,the result is a complete mess!
I try also to style the div directly in html but the result still the same.
I really don't understand how handle the margin and padding properties inside the columns in bootstrap.

Comment: If you want to add a margin on the right side of the title, why are you trying to set a left hand margin?

Comment: Sorry i was wrong when i wrote the question,i want right margin of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a space or margin on the right by doing this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right text-uppercase">
           <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
          <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can just add `padding-right: XXpx;` to the col-md-6 with text.

Comment: So you mean that i can also use a paragraph in col-6 and i put in his style the padding-right attribute?

Comment: No no, the padding property should be added to the column, not the elements inside Coogle